# Difference between filter and list comprehension

Tags: python, list, filter, list-comprehension

I am using Python 3, my question is why is the output different?

```
print([x * x for x in range(2, 5, 2) if x % 4 == 0]) # returns [16]

q = [x * x for x in range(2, 5, 2)]
print(list(filter(lambda x: x % 4 == 0, q))) # returns [4, 16]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
print(([x * x for x in range(2, 5, 2) if x % 4 == 0]))
```

here, `range` evaluates to [2,4] and only `[4]` is able to get past the if condition

```
q = ([x * x for x in range(2, 5, 2)])
print(list(filter(lambda x: x % 4 == 0, q)))
```

here, `q` contains `x*x` of each element, hence the list is `[2*2, 4*4] = [4, 16]`, and both elements get past filter selector

Answer (score 2):

Because `q` contains *squares*

```
In [2]: q
Out[2]: [4, 16]
```

and `lambda x: x % 4 == 0` will return `True` for both of them:

```
In [3]: 4 % 4 == 0
Out[3]: True

In [4]: 16 % 4 == 0
Out[4]: True
```

The list comprehension squares numbers ***after*** performing the check, which fails for 2 (*2 % 4* is *2*):

```
In [5]: 2 % 4 == 0
Out[5]: False
```

Therefore, *2 * 2 = 4* won't be included in the list.

In short, if you want to get the same behaviour, modify your list comprehension to square numbers before computing the remainder:

```
[x * x for x in range(2, 5, 2) if pow(x, 2, 4) == 0] # [4, 16]
#                                   ↖ equivalent to (x ** 2) % 4
```

Answer (score 1):

In the former, each item in `[2,4]` is checked against `x % 4 == 0`. In the latter, `filter` applies the lambda to each item in `q`, which is *not* `[2,4]`, but rather `[4,16]`. Hence, `x % 4 == 0` returns true twice.